# MacOSX(Mavericks/Yosemite)でGNU APLのために文字ビューアを定義する方法を知りたい

Tags: macos

MacOSX Mavericks(10.9)またはYosemite(10.10)で、自分自身で文字ビューアを定義する方法はありますか？
もしくは、文字ビューアのリソースがある場所はどこでしょうか。

目的はGNU APL用のAPL文字を入力するための文字パレットを作りたい、というものです。

Comment: @houmeiさん、「文字ビューアを定義する」とは具体的にどのようなことをしようとしているのか、もう少し詳しく教えてください。この質問はプログラミングに関するものですか？それともMacの一般的な使用方法に関するものでしょうか？

Comment: 目的はGNU APLの利用です。APL文字の入力のために文字ビューアが自分で定義できないかどうか調べていましたがわかりませんでした。

Comment: @houmeiさん、ありがとうございます。タイトルとタグに`GNU-APL`を追加させていただきました。タイトルと質問文は再編集することが可能ですので、お気に召さない場合はお手数ですが削除してください。

Answer (score 1):

文字ビューワの回答ではありませんが、MacでAPL記号を入力する方法です。

[GNU APLのメーリングリストによれば](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-apl/2014-03/msg00126.html)、商用のDyalog APLのキーボード定義ファイルとフォントを使いましょうとのこと(^^;　非商用利用のラインセンスもあるので問題はないかと思いますが、ご自身の判断でお使いください。

以下の手順は101USキーボード用です。106JPキーボードでは定義ファイルの修正が必要でしょう。XMLなので若干の修正で対応できるはずです。

1. [APL385 UNICODE フォント](http://www.dyalog.com/uploads/files/download.php?file=fonts_and_keyboards/Apl385.ttf) [APL333フォント](http://www.dyalog.com/uploads/files/download.php?file=fonts_and_keyboards/APL333.ttf)をダウンロードして`/Library/Fonts`にコピー
2. [キーボードレイアウト定義](http://www.dyalog.com/uploads/files/download.php?file=DyalogAltUS.zip)をダウンロードして解凍後`/Library/Keyboard Layouts`にコピー
3. System PreferencesのキーボードでInput SourcesでDyalog Alt USを追加
4. あとはエディタなどのアプリを開いて、入力をDyalog Alt USに切り替えて、オプションキーを押しながら当該のキャラクターのキーを押せば入力できます。Unicodeならフォントは切り替えなくても問題ないようです。メールアプリなど普通のアプリでも入力できました。

キーボードのレイアウトは[こちら](http://docs.dyalog.com/14.1/Dyalog%20APL%20for%20Mac%20OS%20Installation%20and%20Configuration%20Guide.pdf#page=13&zoom=auto,88,734)にあります。

Answer (score 0):

文字ビューアを作るのではなく標準の文字ビューアを使うのが簡単ではないでしょうか。メニューバーの入力ソースアイコンをクリックして「文字ビューアを表示」から標準の文字ビューアを開けます。 APL 記号を検索して「よく使う項目に追加」を押すと APL 記号のパレットが作れます。

ご自分で専用の文字ビューアを作りたいということでしたら、 Mac の広汎な GUI プログラミングの知識が必要になります。 [Mac Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/) や参考書などをご覧の上で、分からない箇所を個別に質問したほうがよいかと思います。

[gnu-apl-symbols.el](https://github.com/lokedhs/gnu-apl-mode/blob/master/gnu-apl-symbols.el) には APL 記号の一覧および記号と読み方とキーの対応が書かれています。これも参考になるかもしれません。